# I want to add single image multiple times as per count received from User

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add single image multiple times, the count I will get from user. I want to add this image in particular class which will be in slick-slider cards.

I have tried JavaScript where I show image by for loop, but it get visible in only one card
all cards have different amount of images

HTML:

```
<div class="testimonialCarousel">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="testimonialCard">
                        <div class="ratingStar"></div>
                        <div class="testimonialContent">
                            <p class="testimonailText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Augue orci sem nisi arcu sed faucibus fermentum. Ipsum sed morbi dapibus libero id massa fermentum id lorem justo.</p>
                            <p class="authorName">Ajit Babaleshwar</p>
                        </div>       
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="testimonialCard">
                        <div class="ratingStar"></div>
                        <div class="testimonialContent">
                            <p class="testimonailText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Eu egestas non etiam netus velit vitae non tortor at. Viverra tempus nunc eget aliquam. Cursus sit elementum bibendum in duis amet in. Pulvinar turpis purus nunc nunc tellus. Suscipit pellentesque neque faucibus urna cursus.</p>
                            <p class="authorName">Nahia Colunga</p>
                        </div>       
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="testimonialCard">
                        <div class="ratingStar"></div>
                        <div class="testimonialContent">
                            <p class="testimonailText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Eget dictumst est neque suspendisse arcu ullamcorper. Nascetur faucibus faucibus habitant auctor. Dui tortor nullam aliquam et. Amet et consectetur gravida sed ullamcorper dui odio. Sit natoque fusce egestas amet etiam cras.</p>
                            <p class="authorName">Ajit Babaleshwar</p>
                        </div>       
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="testimonialCard">
                        <div class="ratingStar"></div>
                        <div class="testimonialContent">
                            <p class="testimonailText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Augue orci sem nisi arcu sed faucibus fermentum. Ipsum sed morbi dapibus libero id massa fermentum id lorem justo.</p>
                            <p class="authorName">Ajit Babaleshwar</p>
                        </div>       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
   var numberOfRating = 5;
    var theLeftSide = document.querySelectorAll(".ratingStar");
    ratingsRow()
    function ratingsRow() {
      for(i = 0; i < numberOfRating; i++) {
        var stars = document.createElement("img");
        stars.src = "assets/images/rating.png";
        theLeftSide[0].appendChild(stars);
     }

   }
```

Comment: _"but it get visible in only one card"_ - well of course it does, when you _explicitly_ target the first `.ratingStar` element only: `theLeftSide[0].appendChild(...)`

Comment: You want to do something five times, for X number of cards - so there should be _two_ loops, nested into each other.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for quick response, I tried removing [0] , getting error "appendChild" is not function, I am not very good in JavaScript,  Can you please help

Comment: Of course you can't just remove the index, then you are not accessing an individual element any more, but the NodeList that querySelectorAll returned - and you can't append an element to a _list_ of nodes. Instead of removing the index, you need to _go through_ all of them - append elements to `theLeftSide[0]` first, then to `theLeftSide[1]`. And because you don't want to hard-code that, my hint that this should be _two_ nested loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may work if I understood what you wanted.
With as specified by @CBroe two loops, one to go through each DIV of class "ratingStar" and one to insert the images

```
var numberOfRating = 5;

// For each Element with class "ratingStar"
$('.ratingStar').each(function(index){
    

    // For each Rating
    for(i=0;i<numberOfRating;i++)
    {
        // Create Image
        var stars = document.createElement("img");
        stars.src = "rating.png";

        // Append Image
        $(this).append(stars);
    }
    // End - For each Rating

});
// End - each Element with class "ratingStar"
```

Comment: Thank you @Juan , Got what I was missing, Above Code worked with few changes for me .. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Updated little Above code by @juan, and below code worked for me,

```
var cardDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('testimonialCard');

        for (var i=0; i<cardDivs.length; i++) {

            //Below logic is for getting count from card
            var selectedDiv = cardDivs[i];
            var val = selectedDiv.getElementsByClassName('starsToShow')[0].value;
            var starCount = parseInt(val);
            
            //appending star logic below

            let starElement = selectedDiv.getElementsByClassName('ratingStar')[0];
            for(let j = 0; j < starCount; j++){
                var stars = document.createElement("img");
            stars.src = "rating.png";
                starElement.append(stars);
            }
        }
```